# how can i acces students details of class1 as classes/class1

Tags: json, python-3.x, ubuntu

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/classes/<class1>')
def classes(class1):
     class1 = {
  "student1":[ {"id": "0",
                "name": "vijay",
                "class": "1st",
                "teacher": "radha",},
            ],

  "student2":[ {"id": "1",
                "name": "sai",
                "class": "1st",
                "teacher": "yadhav"},
     ],
     }
     return jsonify(class1)

app.run()
```

error:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Apr/2019 10:06:14] "GET /classes/class1 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
how can i clear this issue

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)